# Changing development environment to 64 bit Windows 7 - app crashes

Tags: .net, frameworks, 32bit-64bit

I maintain an application that was originally built in Visual Studio 2005, Framework 2.0, using a Windows XP 32 bit development machine.

My new development machine is Windows 7 64 bit.

I loaded my solution into Visual Studio 2010 and successfully converted all projects (there are several that the actual application uses), and updated to Framework 4.0.

In debug mode, the application runs without a problem.

Now, the way this works is that there was only one installer ever deployed.  Changes are deployed to a server.  When the application is run after installation, it actually runs an updater app to check for file changes vs the server, and if any are found, they are then downloaded, replacing the original files on the client, and then the "real" application is run.

After deploying my first version compiled on my 64 bit machine to the server, I ran the installed version of the application to test if it works ok.  The updater appeared to work fine, but when it launches the "real" app, it crashes.

Run on Windows 7, it crashes with:

Faulting application name: ProviderDesktop.exe, version: 2.6.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f4fad5e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16850, time stamp: 0x4e211485
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0x2388
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccf8971407b4fe
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\UHINt2.5\ProviderDesktop.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 53717437-648a-11e1-a455-8a2e36aa00e8

Run on XP, it crashes with:

EventType : clr20r3     P1 : providerdesktop.exe     P2 : 2.6.1.1
P3 : 4f4fad5e     P4 : providerdesktop     P5 : 2.6.1.1     P6 : 4f4fad5e
P7 : 85d     P8 : 0     P9 : system.io.fileloadexception

I've performed 2 diagnoses so far after googling the problem.

First, I tried Fusion logging.  Nothing was found.

Second, I tried DependencyWalker, loading the faulty app on the Windows 7 development machine.  It showed a missing IESHIMS.DLL.  Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003577/building-c-sharp-for-windows-7-32-bit-platform-on-windows-7-64-bit-machine) post, I located IESHIMS.DLL, but noticed in DependencyWalker that it actually expected the DLL to be in the application's root folder.  I placed it there, re-ran DependencyWalker and that error was gone.  However, there is another error which I strongly suspect is the root cause of the problem:  Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

Every module listed in DependencyWalker is x64, except the ieshims.dll and my actual .exe which are x86.  Both the Updater and Real apps are targeting x86 platform.

Some colleagues had suggested before that I may have problems due to 3rd party references in Real app.  From what I can see here, that doesn't seem to be the case.

If someone could help me get a handle on this, I'd definitely appreciate it as I really don't have much knowledge of lower level concepts such as x86/x64.  It'd mean the difference between getting to develop on a nice fast machine in 2010/.NET 4.0 and having to keep a VM around of XP/32 just for this application which has serious performance issues and developing in 2005/.NET 2.0.

My goal is to be able to develop the application on Win7x64, 2010, 4.0 and have the updater update clients' versions of the applilcation without issues.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to mix assemblies explicitly targeted at 32 and 64 bit.

Have you tried changing all of your targets to Any CPU?

Answer (score 0):

.Net works perfectly on 64-bit machines if it doesn't contain unsafe code. Unsafe code most of the time needs corrections to work in native 64-bit mode.

But, you can ask your application to work in WOW (Windows on Windows) mode, in which case your application will work exactly like on 32-bit machines. It is enabled in project properties, setting Platform target to x86 instead of Any CPU.